# Where does Wordpress get the formatting for the standard post type

Tags: wordpress

I would like to change the formatting of a standard post type but I can't seem to find where to modify the formatting.  Is this something inherited form wp-includes or something?

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "formatting"? Are you referring to the way the editor renders the post content, or the CSS for posts, or the template for the layout of post content on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this shortcode:

(Paste this code at the end of your functions.php)

```
function my_formatter($content) 
{
    $new_content = '';
    $pattern_full = '{(\[raw\].*?\[/raw\])}is';
    $pattern_contents = '{\[raw\](.*?)\[/raw\]}is';
    $pieces = preg_split($pattern_full, $content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

    foreach ($pieces as $piece) {
        if (preg_match($pattern_contents, $piece, $matches)) {
            $new_content .= $matches[1];
        } else {
            $new_content .= wptexturize(wpautop($piece));
        }
    }

    return $new_content;
}
```

Usage:
In admin panel, go to the post and type the content in between "[raw]" & "[/raw]".
[raw] Your Content [/raw]